# Example Project for spring and hibernate with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good sample applications using Spring and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531096/what-are-some-good-sample-applications-using-spring-and-hibernate)

i'm new to spring mvc 3.0.2 and hibernate 3.5 Final, can you please any one give example project for spring and hibernate with annotation. i'm using netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 2):

The [petclinic project](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) should be what you are looking for

(I would suggest getting spring 3.1.M2 and hibernate 3.6.x - they are the latest versions)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [good example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/) to get started with spring+hibernate with annotations. But this example uses maven, i guess that is not a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

[appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) gives template application on which you can build your own.

Working [demo Spring MVC + Spring + Hibernate](http://demo.appfuse.org/appfuse-spring)  and [instructions](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Demos+and+Videos)

Use username admin and password admin to login as an administrator - user/user will allow you to login as a user.